# jQuery no alert array data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

## Array from result;

```
 {"autor":"Testando","publication":"a"}{"autor":"Testando","publication":"a"}{"autor":"Testando","publication":"asa"}{"autor":"Testando","publication":"a"}
```

**PHP;**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $autor = $rows['Nome']; 
    $publication = $rows['publication'];
    $my = array(
    "autor"=>"$autor",
    "publication"=>"$publication"
    );  
    echo json_encode($my);      
    }
```

## Javascript;

```
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                     $(data).each(function(autor, pubication) {
                     alert(data.autor + " : " + data.publication) 
                     });
            }
```

> My problem: jQuery no alert the data
>
> I think the problem is because there is no comma between the results, because when there is only one result, he warns normally in the future want to make a .append in the data, but I can not simply alert data, can anyone help?

Comment: You simply get no alert because your JS is expecting JSON, and your PHP returns a String that is not valid JSON. So your `success` function is not executed. And there is a typo in your JS: `pubication`

Comment: Use both answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what you said. Try to do this:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $arr = array();
    while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $autor = $rows['Nome']; 
        $publication = $rows['publication'];
        $my = array(
        "autor"=>"$autor",
        "publication"=>"$publication"
        );  
        $arr[] = $my;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: thanks for help, my php and js he was wrong; thanks for fix my php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the you are using the [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function wrong.

```
$(data).each(function(i, value) {
    alert(value.autor + " : " + value.publication) 
});
```

Comment: thanks for help, my php and js he was wrong; thanks for fix my js

Comment: @MarleneOliveira well, I did what I could... :)

Comment: man, how I append the data after this? tryed $('#response').append(value.autor + " : " + value.publication); and failed :/